# Show the URL preview in the bottom left of the browser for a clickable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I have made a div clickable using jquery.   Is there a way to also tell the browser to display the target of the clickable div like it does for anchors? (example in the bottom left of the image below)

[image]

In answer to those suggesting using an anchor tag - That's not the question I asked.  I want to avoid using anchor tags as that requires changing a lot of html, rather than a small amount of jquery.  And even if changing the html to use anchors is the correct thing to do - it will still be useful to know if this is possible.

**Edit** it seems this is not easilly possible, but an alternative suggested by [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete), using jquery to wrap the div in an anchor works fine (better than I thought it would)

Comment: By making it clickable what do you mean? is it going to go off to another page?  If so why not just wrap the div in an anchor tag rather than making it redirect?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that.   The page is full of these divs. It was created by someoene else.  Making the divs clickable in jquery meant writing a tiny bit of code.  Adding the anchor tag means changing a huge bunch of html.

Comment: Why hack browser? Respect the semantic, use an anchor.

Comment: I'm not asking if I can hack the browser.  I'm asking if there's a way that this behaviour is possible using jquery.

Comment: it's also a tiny bit of code with jquery to [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) them in an anchor: `$('div.class').wrap('<a href="#link-here"></a>')`

Comment: Thanks Pete.  That's a good answer.  But in answer to GG - why do you think people use jquery?  Making a div clickable is a common thing to do.  I simply asked if I could add this bit of functionality.

Comment: Hide a redirect behind a div clickable isn't a common thing. And it should not be.

Comment: Well I've seen it asked about and suggested many times on dev sites and question sites such as this.  I'm not trying to 'hide' anything.  You make it sound like my motives are insincere,  I am simply trying to convert a div that already existed into a button that can take the user to the target page.

Comment: Ok good luck then. :) I'll follow the topic for observing the answers.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry if I got defensive.  Stackoverflow can be very confrontational these days :) .  It looks like the answer is to use jquery to dynamically add the anchor as Pete suggests.  I just hoped there'd be a built in aspect of the browsers that would allow javascript to control that little preview thing.

Comment: To be honest, I thought wrapping the div in a tag would cause issues,  but I've just tried it and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a normal link and hide it:

```css
a {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">hidden link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid changing the html to include an anchor.  There is a lot of html to change, whereas doing this in jquery took a tiny bit of code.

Comment: It is illegal to nest anchor tags in HTML so if you're trying to get around that by using an `onclick` function, this is not a valid solution